# How to create multiple data frame graphs side by side in a single PDF file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, python-3.8

I am trying to generate graphs using a csv report through pandas. I am able to generate the graphs individually and save them, but I would like to plot all the graphs side by side in a single pdf file and email the pdf every week.

```
[
 {
   "PartitionKey": "Mumbain Indins",
   "RowKey": "abc1123",
   "batsman": "Rohit Sharma",
   "MatchDate": "2022-06-29T19:26:02.000+0000",
   "IncidentType": "batsman",
   "IssueType": "Runout",
   "Runs": 120,
   "FIELD8": ""
 },
 {
   "PartitionKey": "Mumbain Indins",
   "RowKey": "abc1143",
   "batsman": "Rohit Sharma",
   "MatchDate": "2022-08-09T21:42:51.000+0000",
   "IncidentType": "batsman",
   "IssueType": "Runout",
   "Runs": 140,
   "FIELD8": ""
 },
 {
   "PartitionKey": "Mumbain Indins",
   "RowKey": "abc1241",
   "batsman": "Rohit Sharma",
   "MatchDate": "2022-08-10T15:51:29.000+0000",
   "IncidentType": "batsman",
   "IssueType": "Bowled",
   "Runs": 80,
   "FIELD8": ""
 },
 {
   "PartitionKey": "Mumbain Indins",
   "RowKey": "abc1567",
   "batsman": "Rohit Sharma",
   "MatchDate": "2022-08-18T19:35:12.000+0000",
   "IncidentType": "batsman",
   "IssueType": "Catch",
   "Runs": 40,
   "FIELD8": ""
 },
 {
   "PartitionKey": "Mumbain Indins",
   "RowKey": "abc1874",
   "batsman": "Rohit Sharma",
   "MatchDate": "2022-08-24T10:12:24.000+0000",
   "IncidentType": "batsman",
   "IssueType": "hitwicket",
   "Runs": 32,
   "FIELD8": ""
 },
 {
   "PartitionKey": "Mumbain Indins",
   "RowKey": "abc1234",
   "batsman": "Rohit Sharma",
   "MatchDate": "2022-08-26T17:55:22.000+0000",
   "IncidentType": "batsman",
   "IssueType": "lbw",
   "Runs": 100,
   "FIELD8": ""
 },
 {
   "PartitionKey": "Mumbain Indins",
   "RowKey": "abc1987",
   "batsman": "Rohit Sharma",
   "MatchDate": "2022-09-26T10:44:47.000+0000",
   "IncidentType": "batsman",
   "IssueType": "lbw",
   "Runs": 123,
   "FIELD8": ""
 },
 {
   "PartitionKey": "Mumbain Indins",
   "RowKey": "abc143",
   "batsman": "Bumra",
   "MatchDate": "2022-10-09T15:54:50.000+0000",
   "IncidentType": "Bowler",
   "IssueType": "bowled",
   "Runs": 25,
   "FIELD8": ""
 },
 {
   "PartitionKey": "Mumbain Indins",
   "RowKey": "abc1345",
   "batsman": "Karthik",
   "MatchDate": "2022-10-14T18:15:35.000+0000",
   "IncidentType": "Wikcet Keeper",
   "IssueType": "Bowled",
   "Runs": 43,
   "FIELD8": ""
 },
 {
   "PartitionKey": "Mumbain Indins",
   "RowKey": "abc1445",
   "batsman": "Bumra",
   "MatchDate": "2022-10-27T14:57:29.000+0000",
   "IncidentType": "Bowler",
   "IssueType": "Runout",
   "Runs": 256,
   "FIELD8": ""
 },
 {
   "PartitionKey": "Mumbain Indins",
   "RowKey": "abc1987",
   "batsman": "Bumra",
   "MatchDate": "2022-11-02T17:21:41.000+0000",
   "IncidentType": "Bowler",
   "IssueType": "stumped",
   "Runs": 2,
   "FIELD8": ""
 },
 {
   "PartitionKey": "Mumbain Indins",
   "RowKey": "abc1786",
   "batsman": "Bumra",
   "MatchDate": "2022-11-03T15:39:12.000+0000",
   "IncidentType": "Bowler",
   "IssueType": "hitwicket",
   "Runs": 0,
   "FIELD8": ""
 },
 {
   "PartitionKey": "Mumbain Indins",
   "RowKey": "abc8723",
   "batsman": "Bumra",
   "MatchDate": "2022-11-03T16:10:41.000+0000",
   "IncidentType": "Bowler",
   "IssueType": "catch",
   "Runs": 10,
   "FIELD8": ""
 }
]
```

In adition to the images, want to save table as is also along with images

Comment: If you wanted to try Plotly, you could easily do that using subplots. It would be helpful if you had sample data to share.

Comment: I have updated some sample data which is similar to what i am using in my project

Comment: could you please post the data as a dictionary? That way it can more easily be read into a Pandas dataframe. Try `df.head(10).to_dict()`

Comment: Updated the data as dictionary